# Make a new random number after guess is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a very basic guessing game that generates a random number at the start. The problem is that if I guess correctly the number stays the same. I've messed around ALOT with where I should place the RNG, but it either doesn't work, or the code wont compile.

```
import random
import time

r = round(random.uniform(1,10))
print (r)

def start():
    global r
    n = int(input("Guess: "))
    while (r != n):
        if (r < n):
            print("Too big")
            time.sleep(.1)
            start()
        if (r > n):
            print("Too small")
            time.sleep(.1)
            start()
            r = round(random.uniform(1,10))
    if(r == n):
        print("You win!")
        start()
start()
```

Comment: Just call random.uniform each time. Remove all that global-stuff and outer-scope defs. Not needed (and really terrible style)! Just set ```r``` to ```random.uniform()``` right after the function-def. After one more look: there is much more wrong with this code. I highly highly recommend going through a basic python course first! And one more remark: python-code is not really *compiled*. It's *interpreted*.

Comment: Why are you calling start() if they win? Also, the whole point of the whole loop is so you don't need to call recursively

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't know `python` but the solution is:

```
import random
import time

r = round(random.uniform(1,10))
print (r)
def start():
    global r
    n = int(input("Guess: "))
    while (r != n):
        if (r < n):
            print("Too big")
            time.sleep(.1)
            start()
        if (r > n):
            print("Too small")
            time.sleep(.1)
            start()
        if(r == n):
            print("You win!")
            r = round(random.uniform(1,10))
            start()
start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
r = round(random.uniform(1,10))
```

Again. This will set `r` to whatever `uniform()` will return now.

---

Or even better: change this:

```
r = round(random.uniform(1,10))
print (r) 

def start():
    global r
    ...
```

To this:

```
def start():
     r = round(random.uniform(1,10))
     print (r) 
    ...
```

Using global is bad practice, *the best use of global is no global at all*. And if you want to set a new random variable with each call of a function, just put it *in* the function.

---

And I agree with sascha:

> After one more look: there is much more wrong with this code. I highly
>   highly recommend going through a basic python course first!